# Full text Sql query

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing a query to search mysql table using full-text search :

```
select title, 
  MATCH(title,sidebarTxt,introTxt,fullTxt) AGAINST ('MY KEYWORDS' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS score 
from tbl_news
where (status='published') 
order by score DESC
```

The above query is working perfectly. But, if I try to use 'score' in the where clause MySql is throwing me error "#1054 - Unknown column 'score' in 'where clause'. Here is the code that is not working :

```
select title, 
  MATCH(title,sidebarTxt,introTxt,fullTxt) AGAINST ('MY KEYWORDS' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS score 
from tbl_news
where status='published' and score > 0 
order by score DESC
```

I would be really grateful if you could help me to understand it.

Comment: It is giving me following error : #1054 - Unknown column 'score' in 'where clause'. Thanx

Comment: What is the where clause you're trying to that give you this error? Please give us the query you ARE doing that give the error.

Comment: @iight is right. This works as expected.

Comment: Yea I'm not sure what posting a code that he knows works will do to help us help him. We need the code that is 'broken' in order to 'fix' it.

Comment: I did not write the "where" clause in my question. If I write the query like this : ".... from tbl_news where status = 'published' and score > 0 order by score DESC" , then MySql throwing me error "Unknown column 'score' in 'where clause"

Comment: No, It is not working. Here is my full code. I double checked everything : select t.id,t.title,t.introTxt, t.dt, t.link, MATCH(title,sidebarTxt,introTxt,fullTxt) AGAINST ('text' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS score from tbl_news as t where (status='published') and score>0 order by score

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `score` in the `WHERE` clause if `score` is a calculated column. You must set it in an additional `HAVING` clause to apply the condition *after* the calculation:

```
SELECT title, 
  MATCH(title,sidebarTxt,introTxt,fullTxt)
      AGAINST ('MY KEYWORDS' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS score 
FROM tbl_news
WHERE status='published'
HAVING score > 0
ORDER BY score DESC;
```

A test case (with a different table). Here `host` is a column, `host2` is a derived column. Of course column derivation and selection are bogus and make little sense:

```
mysql> use mysql;
Database changed
mysql> select host, UPPER(host) as host2 FROM user WHERE host = 'nottingham';
+------------+------------+
| host       | host2      |
+------------+------------+
| nottingham | NOTTINGHAM |
+------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select host, UPPER(host) as host2 FROM user WHERE host = 'nottingham' AND host2 = 'NOTTINGHAM';
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'host2' in 'where clause'
mysql> select host, UPPER(host) as 'host2' FROM user WHERE host = 'nottingham' AND host2 = 'NOTTINGHAM';
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'host2' in 'where clause'
mysql> select host, UPPER(host) as `host2` FROM user WHERE host = 'nottingham' AND host2 = 'NOTTINGHAM';
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'host2' in 'where clause'

mysql> select host, UPPER(host) as host2 FROM user WHERE host = 'nottingham' HAVING host2 = 'NOTTINGHAM';
+------------+------------+
| host       | host2      |
+------------+------------+
| nottingham | NOTTINGHAM |
+------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Yes this one is correct. Adding quotes was suppressing my error but could not solve it as I was getting empty result. Now it makes sense. Thank you....

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `score` value is not known for all rows until the query finished running. Therefore, this is not possible to apply a condition on `score` using the `WHERE` clause. The `ORDER BY` is executed after all result rows have been computed, so there is no problem using it.

Try using `HAVING`:

```
SELECT title, MATCH(title,sidebarTxt,introTxt,fullTxt) AGAINST ('MY KEYWORDS' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS score
FROM tbl_news
WHERE status='published'
HAVING score > 0
ORDER BY score DESC
```

The `HAVING` clause behaves almost like `WHERE`, with the difference that is executes **after** the results rows have been computed. At this point, the value of `score` is known for each result row, and the condition can be applied.

Documentation:
[Fulltext search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html): have a look to the examples, they use `HAVING`
[Syntax of SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html): have a look at the part about `HAVING` usage

Answer (score 0):

edit: **WRONG**

Try adding single quotes to: `as 'score'`... It seems it doesn't recognize the name you designated that column as.

Comment: Yes....Thank you so much...I was working hard on this for last 2 hours and your suggestion has saved my day. Thank you....

Comment: No Problem...its problems like these that always kill me. It helps to have someone else look over it if you've been working too hard on one thing :)

Comment: Interesting, I never put quotes around my order by alias and they work fine... Dammit, now I will have to try to figure out why this worked here :(

Comment: Excuse me: you changed "AS score" to "AS 'score'" and this made the query work?

Comment: Yes. And I cannot seem to reproduce this behaviour on MySQL 5.5.25, so this REALLY intrigues me :-)

Comment: I usually use single quotes when setting using: as 'some_row'...is this not required as far as you know?

Comment: My Mysql version is "5.5.15".

Comment: It is recommended if you risk using reserved words; usually a backtick is used, AFAIK. I confess, I tend to use neither... @sudip, can you try with HAVING? It is working for me in a simpler setup, so I don't know if I got it right, or merely lucky.

Comment: @iight Adding quotes was suppressing my error but could not solve it as I was getting empty result. Please have a look at Mr. lserni's Post. I had to use having clause as score is a calculate column.

Comment: Adding quotes around `score` will probably return the string "score" for each result row. Even if it fixes the syntax error, the new query will definitely not return the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

This is very likely a case of the 50% noise case. When you have a word that is in 50% or more of the rows, mysql considers it a *noise* word and will ignore it when scoring (and therefore ranking). This only applies to the `NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE` option.

Not to nitpick, but it should work perfectly well without any quotes:

```
mysql> select * from table1;
+---------+------+------+-------------+
| autonum | ID   | name | metavalue   |
+---------+------+------+-------------+
|       1 |    1 | Rose | Drinker     |
|       2 |    1 | Rose | Nice Person |
|       3 |    1 | Rose | Runner      |
|       4 |    2 | Gary | Player      |
|       5 |    2 | Gary | Funny       |
|       6 |    2 | Gary | NULL        |
|       7 |    2 | Gary | Smelly      |
+---------+------+------+-------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select ID, group_concat(coalesce(metavalue,'Empty')) as Test from table1 group by ID order by Test;
+------+----------------------------+
| ID   | Test                       |
+------+----------------------------+
|    1 | Drinker,Nice Person,Runner |
|    2 | Player,Funny,Empty,Smelly  |
+------+----------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select ID, group_concat(coalesce(metavalue,'Empty')) as Test from table1 group by ID order by Test desc;
+------+----------------------------+
| ID   | Test                       |
+------+----------------------------+
|    2 | Player,Funny,Empty,Smelly  |
|    1 | Drinker,Nice Person,Runner |
+------+----------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Server version: 5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 (Ubuntu)
```

(and this sort of query works perfectly fine on my Windows 5.1.x install at work as well)

Comment: No...Its no 50% noise case. I had to add single quote (may be double quote works too) around 'score'.

Comment: @light *What* double quotes? The question didn't have any quotes in it, and column aliases work fine in an order by statement.